# How to detect null JSON value in Swift 3?

Tags: json, swift3

I have a JSON object like this:

```
{
    "access_token" = 593d6d5d5eca0;
    "expires_in" = never;
    user =     {
    fullname = name;
    "profile_picture_url" = "<null>";
    };
}
```

And here is my code to parse `"profile_picture_url"`:

```
let profPicURL = URL(string: userData["profile_picture_url"] as! String)
let profPicData = NSData(contentsOf: profPicURL!)
let profilePicture = UIImage(data: profPicData as! Data)
```

But I got an error since the value of `"profile_picture_url"` was null.
How to parse `"profile_picture_url"` in safe way?

Comment: Learn how to use Optionals, this is very important: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330

Comment: ... And learn to use `!` **sparingly**.

Comment: @EricAya Thanks. I'm new to swift programming. I will learn more deeply on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `if let`

```
if let profileImageString = userData["profile_picture_url"] as? String {
  let profPicURL = URL(string: "Hello moto")
  let profPicData = try? Data(contentsOf: profPicURL!)
  if let profPicData = profPicData {
    let profilePicture = UIImage(data: profPicData)
  }
} else {
  // "profile_picture_url" was null
}
```

Comment: Not worked for me. Got an error "Call can throw but is not marked with 'try'".